# Link issue in html coding

Tags: html

My coding in one of my html webpages, is interfering with a line in the code. I have a social media button that has a link to a Youtube page but the link doesn't only apply to the button, it also makes the line below it a link. Also there seems to be a line running through my social media icons and I'm not really sure why that is. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<body class="contact">

<html>

  <title>TekMillion - Contact</title>

<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="images/TEKMILL%20logo%20RESIZE.png" alt="Tekmill Logo" width="839" height="322"></center></p>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

<HR>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>  
  <li><a href="merchandise.html">Shop</a></li>               
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<HR>

<div class="container">
</br>

<form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         
         <h1 class="title"><center>Contact US</h1></center>
         
      <label></label>
      <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
      
              
      <label></label>
      <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">
              
      
      <label></label>
      <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      
            
      <center><input id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
              
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
         
     </form>
</br>
</br>
<span class="textformat1"><center><b>Social Media</span></center></b>
</br>
<center>
<a href="https://twitter.com/tekmill"> <img src="socialmedia/twitter.jpg" align="middle" alt="Instagram" width="80" height="80">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/TekMillMusic"> <img src="socialmedia/facebook.jpg" align="middle" alt="Facebook" width="80" height="80">
<a href="https://plus.google.com/+TekMillMusic/videos"> <img src="socialmedia/googleplus.jpg" align="middle" alt="Google Plus" width="80" 
height="80">
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/tekmill"> <img src="socialmedia/soundcloud.jpg" align="middle" alt="Soundcloud" width="80" height="80">
<a href="https://youtube.com/tekmillmusic"> <img src="socialmedia/youtube.jpg" align="middle" alt="Youtube" width="80" height="80">
</center>
</br>
</div>
</html>
<hr>
</body>
```

[link problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khXa7.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you haven't closed your `a` tags.

Try

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/tekmill"> <img src="socialmedia/twitter.jpg" align="middle" alt="Instagram" width="80" height="80"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/TekMillMusic"> <img src="socialmedia/facebook.jpg" align="middle" alt="Facebook" width="80" height="80"></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/+TekMillMusic/videos"> <img src="socialmedia/googleplus.jpg" align="middle" alt="Google Plus" width="80"  height="80"></a>
<a href="https://soundcloud.com/tekmill"><img src="socialmedia/soundcloud.jpg" align="middle" alt="Soundcloud" width="80" height="80"></a> 
<a href="https://youtube.com/tekmillmusic"><img src="socialmedia/youtube.jpg" align="middle" alt="Youtube" width="80"  height="80"></a>
```

Note the `</a>` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

**Close** `a` tag and `define` your `a` tag `display` `inline-block` **property** as like this

```
<a href=""></a> 

a{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing any of your ANCHOR tags...

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/tekmill"> <img src="socialmedia/twitter.jpg" align="middle" alt="Instagram" width="80" height="80">
```

should be...

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/tekmill"> <img src="socialmedia/twitter.jpg" align="middle" alt="Instagram" width="80" height="80"> </a>
```

The browser interprets the next A tag as the end of the previous one so you only notice this on the last one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
.container a{

    text-decoration-line: unset;
}
</style>
```